# Any opensource network monitoring system?

Tags: networking, asynchronous, monitoring

I need have a networking monitoring system that have these feature.

1. opensourced (must)
2. written by c/c++. (must)
3. async io mode (like io, must)
4. support ping, http, snmp, mysql, redis... protocal

The System must run with epoll mode so that run many test as there can, no blocking at all.
Is there any avaliable one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you looked on sourceforge for open source software, they have many rated network monitoring systems written in C and C++.  Pandora  is good but look around maybe you might find what you looking for there.>>> [Link](http://sourceforge.net/directory/language%3acpp/language%3ac/os%3awindows/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=network%20monitor)<<<